# Building a String to be treated as a parameterized arguments for Function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gmail-api

I'm trying to use PyGmail API and by default it works like this

```
s = g.inbox().mail(unread=True, sender='someone@gmail.com')
s[0].fetch()
print s[0].subject
```

So now, I want to build the whole bracketed term with certain conditions so I want to basically be able to do something like this:

```
f = "unread=True, sender='someone@gmail.com'"
s = g.inbox().mail(f.decode('string_escape'))
s[0].fetch()
print s[0].subject
```

But this doesn't work because the f variable is still being treated as a string, despite using strin escape decoding.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why can't you build `f` up as a dict?

Comment: Are you looking to modify a string based on a condition? I think u are overcomplicating your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

forming `f` as a string is making your life much harder than it needs to be, and introducing lots of extra possibilities for bugs.

Build a dict of keywords and pass them in the usual way (with `**`)

```
keywords = {}
if something:
    keywords['unread'] = True
else:
    ... 
if somethingelse:
    keywords['sender'] = 'someone@gmail.com'
else:
    ... 

s = g.inbox().mail(**keywords)
```